# Extraneous Properties in Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger Shopify

Tags: facebook, shopify, facebook-opengraph

I have researched this issue on Stackoverflow and elsewhere and though I have found hundreds of pages of information, I have not been able to figure out why the Facebook Object Debugger reports that there are extraneous properties. I have tried it with and without the app_id.

The object debugger show this for [input url](https://www.moodswingsonthenet.com/products/alchemy-england-gothic-fairy-ear-wrap-cuff-left-side-pierced)

```
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:locale'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:site_name'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:title'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:type'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:url'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:image'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:image:secure_url'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:image:type'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:image:width'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:image:height'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'product:price:amount'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'product:price:currency'.
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:description'.
```

But is able to construct the following Open Graph properties:

```
fb:app_id   734911290261034
og:url  https://www.moodswingsonthenet.com/products/alchemy-england-gothic-fairy-ear-wrap-cuff-left-side-pierced
og:type product
og:title    Alchemy England Gothic Fairy Ear Wrap Cuff Left Side Pierced
og:locale   
{
   "locale": "en_us"
og:image    (DOES SHOW IMAGES BUT THERE ARE 2 SETS OF THE SAME IMAGES)
og:description  Authorized Alchemy England retailer and shipped from the USA Whispering fairy left ear wrap for pierced ear Surgical steel post Hypoallergenic - lead, cadmium, and nickel free Made of fine English pewter Handcrafted in England Includes Alchemy England warranty and care instructions Guaranteed to be genuine Alchemy Engl
og:site_name    moodswingsonthenet
og:updated_time 1577676246
product:price   Array of length: 1
{
   "amount": 34.95,
   "currency": "USD"
}
product:is_product_shareable    1
og:image:alt
```

social-meta-tags.liquid

```
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="734911290261034" /> 
    {% comment %}
      Open graph tags
    {% endcomment %}
    {% if template contains 'index' %}
      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      <meta property="og:title" content="Moodswings Inc" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="{{ canonical_url }}" />
      {% if settings.home_page_content != blank %}
        <meta property="og:description" content="{{ pages[settings.home_page_content].content | strip_html | escape }}" />
      {% else %}
        <meta property="og:description" content="{{ page_description }}" />
      {% endif %}

    {% elsif template contains 'product' %}
      <meta property="og:locale" content="en_us" />
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ shop.name }}" />
      <meta property="og:title" content="{{ product.title }}" />
      <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="{{ canonical_url }}" />
     {% for image in product.images limit:3 %} 
      <meta property="og:image" content="http:{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" />
      <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https:{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}">
      <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" /> 
      <meta property="og:image:width" content="{{ image.width | remove: "px"  }}" />
      <meta property="og:image:height" content="{{ image.height | remove: "px"  }}" />
     {% endfor %}
      <meta property="og:price:amount" content="{{ product.price | money_without_currency | strip_html | escape }}" />
      <meta property="og:price:currency" content="USD" />
    {% elsif template contains 'article' %}
      <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
      <meta property="og:title" content="{{ article.title | strip_html }}" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="{{ canonical_url }}" />
      {% if article.image %}
      <meta property="og:image" content="http:{{ article | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" />
      <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https:{{ article | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" />
      {% endif %}
    {% elsif template == 'password' %}
      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      <meta property="og:title" content="{{ shop.name }}" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="{{ shop.url }}" />
      {% if settings.logo_use_image %}
      <meta property="og:image" content="http:{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" />
      <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https:{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" />
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      <meta property="og:title" content="{{ page_title }}" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="{{ canonical_url }}" />
      {% if settings.logo_use_image %}
      <meta property="og:image" content="http:{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" />
      <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https:{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" />
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% unless template contains 'index' %}
    {% if page_description %}
      <meta property="og:description" content="{{ page_description }}" />
    {% endif %}
    {% endunless %}
    {% comment %}
      This snippet renders meta data needed to create a Twitter card.
    {% endcomment %}
    {% if template contains 'article' and article.image %}
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    {% elsif template == 'index' and slider_enabled %}
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    {% else %}
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    {% endif %}
    {% unless settings.social_twitter_url == blank %}
      <meta name="twitter:site" content="@{{ settings.social_twitter_url | split: 'twitter.com/' | last }}" />
    {% endunless %}
    {% if template == 'index' %}
      <meta name="twitter:title" content="{{ page_title }}" />
      {% if settings.home_page_content != blank %}
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="{{ pages[settings.home_page_content].content | strip_html | truncate: 200, '' | escape }}" />
      {% else %}
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="{{ page_description | escape }}" />
      {% endif %}
      {% if slider_enabled %}
        {% for i in (1..6) %}
          {% capture slide %}slide_{{ i }}{% endcapture %}
          {% capture slide_img %}slide_{{ i }}.jpg{% endcapture %}
          {% if settings[slide] %}
            <meta name="twitter:image" content="https:{{ slide_img | asset_img_url: '1024x1024' }}" />
            {% break %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% elsif template contains 'product' %}
      <meta name="twitter:title" content="{{ product.title | strip_html | escape }}" />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content="{{ product.description | strip_html | truncate: 200, '' | escape }}" />
      <meta name="twitter:image" content="https:{{ product | img_url: 'large' }}" />
      <meta name="twitter:image:width" content="480" />
      <meta name="twitter:image:height" content="480" />
    {% elsif template contains 'article' %}
      <meta name="twitter:title" content="{{ article.title | strip_html | escape }}" />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content="{{ article.excerpt_or_content | strip_html | truncate: 200, '' | escape }}" />
      {% if article.image %}
      <meta property="twitter:image" content="https:{{ article | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" />
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
```

Please help me figure out what is wrong with my code, thank you!!

Comment: Actually, I have this above the theme.liquid head tag: <html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"> Not, in the social-meta-tags.liquid file.